# Upload post image url into mysql database, and put multiple urls in one row

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently creating a website were you can also place blog posts with pictures, I already have the code to upload the file but I also want to put it in my MYSQL row.

Here is my post_picture.php:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Profile Pic:</label> <input type="file" name="ProfilePic" id="ProfilePic" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "a1070rik", "");
mysql_select_db("portals",$con);
if(isset($_POST[submit])){
    $ProfilePicName = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["name"];
    $ProfilePicType = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["type"];
    $ProfilePicSize = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["size"];
    $ProfilePicTemp = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["tmp_name"];
    $ProfilePicError = $_FILES["ProfilePic"]["error"];

    $RandomAccountNumber = uniqid();
    move_uploaded_file($ProfilePicTemp, "Content/" . $RandomAccountNumber . ".png");
}
?>
```

Here is a picture of my MYSQL table structure:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qakEH.png)
And also I want to have multiple image url's in one row, is this possible?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Extra information for query:
my database name is "portalen" and the row name is "leerlingen".

Answer (score 1):

First, looking at your phpMySql screenshoot, I suggest you to look at field length documentation. You really don't need a varchar(1000) to save an email address nor a varchar(9999) to store a file name.

For what you want to do, you just need to make a query to MySQL where you going to add the $RandomAccountNumber . ".png" to the img_url field.

WARNING: Your script assumes that the file is a PNG. I suggest you to look at documentantion or some exampleson how to determine the file mime type to add the right extension to the saved file. There's a great example here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Thanks gonna look into that. Do you also maybe know how to put it in my MYSQL row?

Comment: Your post doesn't provide sufficient information in order to build a query for you.

Comment: Need table names, field names and data that you'll need to add on each record together with the file name.

Comment: I already have found the code to put it in the mysql table, the only thing i need to find out now is how to put multiple urls in one row. if thats possible

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with those multiple URLs, how you want use them when querying the table. 

if you want to use multiple images per single record, I would suggest normalizing by adding a second table and relate both tables on one to many. If that is not an option, you can add the multiple file names to an array, serialize it and save it into the desired field. Then when consulting the record, you can just deserialize the value of the field and you'll get an array with the files names.

Comment: Think about a blog post with multiple pictures. I want those multiple picture urls in one row when querying the information

Comment: I understand what you want to do, and what I'm giving you is a generic answer so you can understand how it is usually done, learn, and do it yourself. 
Having somebody giving you a fish is just going to feed you only for one day. 
You seem to want to achieve things without learning how. That's not good. You'll never get things done that way as after this problem you'll find another one, and another one, and another...

Comment: Best for you would be to find a simple php blog CMS, and look at its database and code.

Comment: I understand your point but its hard to make a rod and fish with it if you dont know how to make and use it.

Comment: Thanks im gonna look into that one

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, it might not be the most secure way but it works for now. 
For anybody who wants it here is the code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST[upload])){
    $fileExistsFlag = 0; 
    $fileName = uniqid() . $_FILES['Filename']['name'];
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","a1070rik","","photos") or die("Error ".mysqli_error($link));
    /*
    *   If file is not present in the destination folder
    */
    if($fileExistsFlag == 0) { 
        $target = "files/";     
        $fileTarget = $target.$fileName;    
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["Filename"]["tmp_name"];
        $fileDescription = $_POST['Description'];   
        $result = move_uploaded_file($tempFileName,$fileTarget);
        /*
        *   If file was successfully uploaded in the destination folder
        */
        if($result) { 
            echo "Your file <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> has been successfully uploaded";       
            $query = "INSERT INTO images(filepath,filename,description) VALUES ('$fileTarget','$fileName','$fileDescription')";
            $link->query($query) or die("Error : ".mysqli_error($link));            
        }
        else {          
            echo "Sorry !!! There was an error in uploading your file";         
        }
        mysqli_close($link);
    }
    /*
    *   If file is already present in the destination folder
    */
    else {
        echo "File <html><b><i>".$fileName."</i></b></html> already exists in your folder. Please rename the file and try again.";
        mysqli_close($link);
    }}; 
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>File :</p>
    <input type="file" name="Filename"> 
    <p>Description</p>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="Description"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

And then the code to create the same sql table as I have:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Databank: `photos`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabelstructuur voor tabel `images`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `filepath` varchar(999) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(999) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Just put that code in a .sql file and import it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The code you found may solve your problem but may not be very clear to promote learning and solve other problems.
The code is very insecure for many reasons, some of them very basic, for example: You don't check the file type, and adding rand() doesn't guarantee that you won't have another file with the same name. uniqid() would work better for that purpose.